# MERGE INTO doesn't work in PHP?

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

My `MERGE INTO` statement works in SQL using SQL Developer:

```sql
MERGE INTO EMAIL_LIST d USING (SELECT 'stackoverflowuser95@gmail.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL) s ON (d.EMAIL = s.EMAIL) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (EMAIL) VALUES (s.EMAIL);
```

But doesn't work when attempted in PHP:

```php
$update_or_insert_list = oci_parse($conn,
                                   "MERGE INTO EMAIL_LIST d USING (SELECT :email EMAIL FROM DUAL) s ON (d.EMAIL = s.EMAIL) WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (EMAIL) VALUES (s.EMAIL);"
); // Also tried with ':email' and/or with ; inside the SQL statement

oci_bind_by_name($update_or_insert_list, ':email', $email);

oci_execute($update_or_insert_list);
```

Here is the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMAIL_LIST ( 
    EMAIL VARCHAR2 (100)  NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE EMAIL_LIST
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EMAIL_LIST PRIMARY KEY ( EMAIL ) ;

-- And yes, this is a test-case!
```

#### How do I get MERGE INTO working in PHP?

Comment: Does not work is not saying much. What is the error you get?

Comment: Not getting an error, but no data is being inserted into the Table.

Comment: Are you actually checking for errors?

Comment: Is there a way of changing debug level?

Comment: [oci_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-execute.php) returns a bool, it will be false on error. [oci_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php) returns the last error found. You need error checking in your code to get the actual error.

Comment: Echo your query, and copy paste it in PHPmyadmin or something like that. It most likely gives you then an error

Comment: Okay, I'm getting a "Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in listAdd.php on line 7". I've tried the `htmlentities` and `addslashes` function, but they had no affect.

Comment: If you're going to check the result of `oci_execute` and use `oci_error`, then you might as well just use a plain `insert` and check for an `ORA-00001` error which would indicate that the email address already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a `MERGE` error, remove the ending `;` in your query.

The final semi-colon is not part of the SQL. It is used in various client interface (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer...) to indicate the end of the SQL statement. In PHP each request is a single SQL statement so the semi-colon is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, very odd that it worked this time. See my comment in the code showing that I had already tried that.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser95 maybe it was before you modified your code to check the error message and it was a different error?